# Table-valued parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, table-valued-parameters

It is my understanding that there is no elegant way to call a stored procedure in EF6 using table-valued parameters. Can someone verify or discredit my suspicion?

Table-valued type:

```
CREATE TYPE MyTestType AS TABLE
(
    ID      INT,
    String  VARCHAR(30)
);
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyTestProc
    @TestVar MyTestType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM @TestVar
END
```

C# EF call:

```
var testTable = new DataTable();
testTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof (int));
testTable.Columns.Add("string", typeof (string));
testTable.Rows.Add(1, "Row1");

var parameter = new SqlParameter("@TestVar", SqlDbType.Structured);
parameter.Value = testTable;
parameter.TypeName = "dbo.MyTestType";

var results = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TestObject>("exec dbo.MyTestProc @TestVar", parameter).ToList();
```

The code above is working, I would just like to see if there is a more elegant way of executing it. I feel like I should be allowed to do something like

```
var results = dbContext.MyTestProc(testTable).ToList();
```

**Edit**

I came across this article which has a slightly cleaner way of handling the data table, but still hoping for a cleaner way to call my stored procedure with the table-valued parameter.

[Code.msdn - Stored Procedure with Table-Valued Parameter in EF and ASP.NET MVC](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Stored-Procedure-with-6c194514)